# android taking screenshots programmaticaly Android Screenshot Library issue

Tags: android, service, android-ndk, screenshot, native

What I want to achieve is to capture a current foreground activity and save to bitmap file. I need to handle taking that screenshot in a background service. I have run through many ideas, tutorials that mainly uses invoking `getWindow()` method and enabling cache. However that approach is useless for me - it is impossible to get reference to the foreground running activity (isn't it?) - using `ActivityManager` I can get only the name & package of it.

I came across the ASL (https://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/downloads/detail?name=asl-1.2.zip&can=2&q=)  which uses "native service" which is available in compiled binary file. Library's wiki note states that you have to start the native "screenshot service" by ADB using pc.

**My question is:** could it be possible to start that service programmaticaly  through java code, something like JNI (using NDK) does?

Comment: No, not without breaking the security model of the device (ie, being "rooted").

Comment: IIRC, the shell user is allowed to access the screenshot mechanism as well.  So you don't need the device to be rooted, strictly speaking, you just need to enable ADB debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a rooted device, you can start the service from Java with

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su")
```

On custom system, you can start the service from `/init.rc`.

NDK will not help, anyway. Going C does not compromise the system permissions.